# How to use ExtJs Grid control for auto_complete combobox results?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using ExtJs combobox autocomplete and I want to get the search results in ExtJs Grid. I've read the ExtJs combo documentation in Sencha website and I've found out that the tpl property can be used to make a custom template for search results, but it doesn't accept the ExtJs grid control. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that out of box. tpl property lets you use XTemplate to create whatever HTML structure you want (including a table) but not another Ext component.